# How do I manually install extensions on Chrome for OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have create a chrome extension and i want to add it manually to chrome on mac osx (10.7 and 10.8)

i tried to do the following steps

1. add the extension folder under the following url:
   /Users/talmutzafi/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 20/Extensions/
2. add the extension data under the preferences list. the preferences list is located on 
   /Users/talmutzafi/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 20/preferences

i tried to add :

```
- under backup i added the ext. id to the id's list

       "backup": {
  "_signature": "+1Vx9UrMvhjXj4EFWQAf2eMfrRs+ZrFK3ogVnwE/Njs=",
  "_version": 4,
  "extensions": {
     "ids": [ "ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb", "akheoamkobfngpbmfmnjnekmciamdknh", "apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf", "blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo", "coobgpohoikkiipiblmjeljniedjpjpf", "pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia" ]
  }

- under settings i add the following data on the extension

     "akheoamkobfngpbmfmnjnekmciamdknh": {
        "ack_external": true,
        "active_permissions": {
           "api": [ "bookmarks", "contextMenus", "cookies", "geolocation", "history", "idle", "management", "notifications", "plugin", "tabs", "unlimitedStorage", "webNavigation", "webRequest", "webRequestInternal" ],
           "explicit_host": [ "chrome://favicon/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
           "scriptable_host": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
        },
        "app_launcher_ordinal": "t",
        "events": [ "runtime.onInstalled" ],
        "from_bookmark": false,
        "from_webstore": false,
        "install_time": "13000491448720728",
        "location": 3,
        "manifest": {
           "background": {
              "page": "js/chromeBackStage.html"
           },
           "chrome_url_overrides": {
              "newtab": "Search/NewTabPages/html/new_tab.html"
           },
           "current_locale": "en_US",
           "default_locale": "en_US",
           "description": "mac installer",
           "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDIl5KlKwL2TSkntkpY3naLLz5jsN0YwjhZyObcTOK6Nda4Ie21KRqZau9lx5SHcLh7pE2/S9OiArb+na2dn7YK5EvH+aRXS1ec3uxVlBhqLdnleVgwgwlg5fH95I52IeHcoeK6pR4hW/Nv39GNlI/Uqk6O6GBCCsAxYrdxww9BiQIDAQAB",
           "manifest_version": 2,
           "name": "mac installer",
           "offline_enabled": true,
           "permissions": [ "storage", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "notifications", "management", "unlimitedStorage", "bookmarks", "contextMenus", "cookies", "geolocation", "history", "idle", "webNavigation", "chrome://favicon/*", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking" ],
           "version": "1.0"
        },
        "page_ordinal": "n",
        "path": "akheoamkobfngpbmfmnjnekmciamdknh/1.0",
        "state": 1,
        "was_installed_by_default": true
     },
```

after changing it i opened chrome and expected to see my extension but the extension didn't appear.

i checked in window and in addition to adding the extension to the preferences we need to write the extension to the registry.

any ideas what else i need to do in order to install manually the chrome extension folder

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this path

**For a specific user:** `~USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions/`

**For all users**: `/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions/`

*If you do not see external extensions installed when Chrome is launched, there may be a permissions problem with the external extensions preferences files.*

#### References

a) [Mac Troubleshooting](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html#troubleshooting) .

b) [Deployment Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html)

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to install extension via crx that's not hosted on chrome store in windows and mac machines. From the documentation, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/external_extensions/ -

*Warning Windows and Mac installs must come from Chrome Web Store: As of Chrome 33, no external installs are allowed from a path to a local .crx on Windows (see Protecting Windows users from malicious extensions). As of Chrome 44, no external installs are allowed from a path to a local .crx on Mac (see Continuing to protect Chrome users from malicious extensions).*