# Manually Install/Add Extension to Chrome on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, install4j

I am developing an installer for Mac using Install4j, where in i need to install a Chrome Extension (.crx file) from the installer. I have tried placing the crx file inside

> ~USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External

and

> /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions/

but non of that worked. I have referenced to this stackoverflow question : [How do I manually install extensions on Chrome for OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976062/how-do-i-manually-install-extensions-on-chrome-for-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, the Deployment options link in the reference url solved the problem for me.