# how to install chrome extension on Mac

Tags: google-chrome-extension, osx-mountain-lion

Does anybody know how to install a chrome extension automatically on Mac (mountain lion)?
I have tried the method mentioned from chrome developper(but I don't see the "External Extensions" folder, and I also unzip the file directly into "Default/ID/Version/**". Both methods can not work.
Thanks

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Actually it works just according to the instruction from chrome developer. But you have to note that: Once you remove the extension manually, it won't work！

Answer (score -1):

You can only install from the chrome store, or by drag&drop of the .crx on the extensions page

Comment: He's talking about http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html. In that case, you can apparently bypass these restrictions.

Comment: @Metoule Yes, you are right, I have tried the method in that link, I feel Mac mountain lion has changed the scheme. I have checked the folder in my machine, there is no "External Extensions" folder. According to the key word "preference" I found one file located in Default/Preferences, I found all extensions installed from store or drag&drop will reflect it's states here. So I tried to modified the state manually and unzip file to corresponding folder, it works. I wonder if the preferences json mechanism is still working on mountain lion?? or we need to move the json file to other places?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I don't have a Mac to test. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/13976062/2698119 can help you though.